# Boxes blur on my site, can't find the css style or whatevers doing it

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I thought I was going crazy, but a colleague confirmed those gradients are there. How do I  remove it?

This will only work on Desktops

On a site www.motosa.co.za - look just right of the Main Menu Bar, seems to be a gradient, darker from left to right?

Can you please help me find and fix the css that causes this. Assuming it is css causing it. It uses the Office theme on Themeforest, and I see those there on the demo as well and the author claims innocence.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is a protected site, can I get a password to look into this?

Comment: I just looked and your menu has all the same color background-color: #2b2b2b; for menus so there's no gradient there. 

Are you talking about the menu or on the gray background of the body?

Comment: Yes of course, Im talking about the gradient running over the background of the body, right next to the menu

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I see there's a custom style that you've added 
'body { background: #fff;}'

But due to low specificity this is being overwritten by theme styles.

You either need to:

1. Go to your Theme Settings and find a background color and change it to #fff.
2. **Or** in your custom styles write:

   body {
           background: #fff !important;
       }

Comment: No, I dont care about the grey bg color. The issue is, if you use Firefox, you can clearly see a gradient stretching from the menu acros the bg

Comment: What version of Firefox are you talking about? I don't see any gradient in firefox. Version 43.0.1 and Firefox 45.0.2

Comment: I hope this will help - www.motosa.co.za/downloads/issue.jpg